Format HTML to layout two columns for printing
I have text with chapters in HTML and would like to have them for print media in a layout with two columns, see picture:

My HTML and CSS looks like this:


@media print {
     @page {
         size: a4;
         margin: 3cm 1.5cm;
    }
     .work {
         font-family: 'ITC Giovanni Std', sans-serif;
    }
     .work h1 {
         font-weight: bold;
         margin-bottom: 0.25cm;
    }
     .work .work-title {
         margin-bottom: 2cm;
    }
     .work .work-title hr {
         width: 2cm;
         opacity: 0.5;
         border: 0;
         border-top: 1px solid;
         color: inherit;
         margin: 1rem 0;
    }
     .work .work-content {
         column-count: 2;
         column-gap: 1em;
         column-span: all;
         column-width: auto;
         text-align: justify;
         hyphens: auto;
         word-break: break-word;
         font-size: 12pt;
         line-height: 1.25em;
    }
     .work .work-content .chapter {
         margin-bottom: 1cm;
    }
     .work .work-content .chapter .chapter-number {
         font-size: 2.25rem;
         font-weight: bold;
    }
}
 
<body>
  <div class="work" lang="de">
    <div class="work-title">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="work-content">
      <p class="chapter">
        <span class="chapter-number">1</span>
        <span>Lorem ipsum ...</span>
      </p>
      <p class="chapter">
        <span class="chapter-number">2</span>
        <span>Lorem ipsum ...</span>
      </p>
      <p class="chapter">
        <span class="chapter-number">3</span>
        <span>Lorem ipsum ...</span>
      </p>
      <p class="chapter">
        <span class="chapter-number">4</span>
        <span>Lorem ipsum ...</span>
      </p>
      <p class="chapter">
        <span class="chapter-number">5</span>
        <span>Lorem ipsum .</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>



The problem I am facing is the small step that appears in the second column:

I understand that this is due to the chapter number. But how do I get the text to be at the same height? What I have already found out is that I can set the line-height to 0 for .chapter-number:


.chapter-number {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0;
}



Then it fits:

Then (but also in general) I am confronted with the problem that if a chapter number is at the beginning of a page, it extends into the previous page:

Which parameters do I need to change in order to achieve my goal?

Your "CSS" looks more like SCSS. As far as I know, regular CSS does not support nested declarations like .chapter-number inside .chapter. The snippet will work better when you convert it to actual CSS.

I converted to CSS, use full page and ctrl-p to see the issue

@mplungjan That does not change anything

@Tobias I did not do it for you. I did it to make the snippet work as expected

@PeterB most browsers support CSS nesting now. Was there a specific problem with how it was being used?
